# showing touch/click points on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw a dot each time the user clicks/touches a point on any web page. Ideally this would be some kind of transparent pane that draws these dots but also allows the clicks/touches to pass through the pane so that original page doesn't lose functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do two things. First of all create a click event listener on your body, that way you will catch all clicks. When clicked, place an dom element, for example a div on that position and format it as you wish.

Secondly look at this: [Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Hope it helps!